# Rotary Encoder gives "wrong" patterns?

Tags: rotary-encoder

I am trying to learn how to use a Rotary Encoder together with an LCD display where I can use the encoder to choose Letters that will be printed in the LCD. 
[image]

This is the kind of result I should be getting, but instead I am getting this:

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16

c  d  e  f  0  1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9   a   b

10 00 10 00 11 01 11 01 10 00  10  00  11  01  11  01

A:
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

B:
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1

Shouldn't I be getting a sort of
001100110
100110011
pattern to be able to tell which way it is rotated?
How can I fix this?
I am using the following connections:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with these patterns. Please explain more, how you get to those patterns and what exactly you didn't expect

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's wrong with your code if we can't see it?

Comment: you are misunderstanding how to use the encoder ... you do not read the two bits and look for patterns ... you wait for `A` to change ... that tells you that the encoder moved ... the state of `B` at the time of the change tells you the direction of rotation ... to make it simple, look for only the rising edge of signal `A`